# C++ using operator int() instead of operator+

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to understand why the `operator int()` is invoked instead of the defined `operator+`

```
class D {
    public:
        int x;
        D(){cout<<"default D\n";}
        D(int i){ cout<<"int Ctor D\n";x=i;}
        D operator+(D& ot){ cout<<"OP+\n"; return D(x+ot.x);}
        operator int(){cout<<"operator int\n";return x;}
        ~D(){cout<<"D Dtor "<<x<<"\n";}
};

void main()
{
    cout<<D(1)+D(2)<<"\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

my output is:

```
int Ctor D
int Ctor D
operator int
operator int
3
D Dtor 2
D Dtor 1
```

Comment: What is your *question*?

Comment: @MikeCAT It's in the first line. What is unclear?

Comment: Remove `operator int()` and you'll see why, or at least you should with most compilers and their default options.

Comment: @Rotem It seems not what you are *asking* but what you are *doing* by yourself.

Comment: @MikeCAT: surely something is wrong with your thinking if everybody else understands the implied question. ah, and btw, he's not the OP.

Comment: Your `operator+` takes a non-const reference parameter and therefore is not eligible to be bound to temporaries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your expression `D(1)+D(2)` involves temporary objects. So you have to change you signature of `operator+` to take by `const-ref`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class D {
    public:
        int x;
        D(){cout<<"default D\n";}
        D(int i){ cout<<"int Ctor D\n";x=i;}
        // Take by const - reference
        D operator+(const D& ot){ cout<<"OP+\n"; return D(x+ot.x);}
        operator int(){cout<<"operator int\n";return x;}
        ~D(){cout<<"D Dtor "<<x<<"\n";}
};

int main()
{
    cout<<D(1)+D(2)<<"\n";
}
```

It prints:

```
int Ctor D
int Ctor D
OP+
int Ctor D
operator int
3
D Dtor 3
D Dtor 2
D Dtor 1
```

The `operator int` is invoked while finding the correct overload for printing it out to `cout`.